# Getting download count for a file using GA api

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

We are trying to write a small PHP service that gets the GA file download count for specific files for a site. Right now, we tried it with the `ga:pageviews` metric, but I am not sure if this is the right metric, as the results are way lower than expected.

The code we used to get the data is this:

```
$analytics->data_ga->get(
  'ga:' . $profileId,
  '2005-01-01',
  'today',
  'ga:pageviews',
  ['filters' => 'ga:pagePath=@' . $url]);
```

Here are the top downloaded files in the GA page:
[Google Analytics files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnjeZ.png)

But the top downloaded file, with the above code returns a pageViews count of just 3.

So, my questions are:

- What is the appropiate metric to get the count of times a file has
  been downloaded?
- Is the code I am using correct?

Answer (score 0):

After checking your picture i can see that you have added your downloads as events in Google analitcs.  This means that you should be using th eevent dimensions and metrics to find the data not pageviews.

[Event dimenisons and metrics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=event_tracking)

I would sugest starting with

```
$analytics->data_ga->get(
  'ga:' . $profileId,
  '2005-01-01',
  'today',
  'ga:totalEvents');
```

Then add these dimensions

```
ga:eventCategory
ga:eventAction
ga:eventLabel
```